# Change of coordinates and a matrix representation of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm working in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Any inner product can be represented with a positive definite matrix $A$ such that $\left<v, w\right> = v^* A w$. Here I want to introduce a new basis. Let $Q$ be the matrix whose columns are the new basis vectors. I'd like to find a matrix $B$ that represents the original inner product in the new basis. How can I express $B$ in terms of $Q$?

Comment: What/how have you learned in your class to convert from one basis to another? Could you apply this technique to your problem?

Comment: @Moritz, I guess the similarity transform $B = Q^{-1}AQ$ should work. However, I failed to argue that it really does.

Comment: In general, it doesn’t. Change of basis for bilinear forms is a bit different from that of transformation matrices. See [leeto’s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1942340/265466) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a matrix $B$ such that $v^* A w = v_0^* B w_0$ where $v_0$ and $w_0$ are representations of $v$ and $w$, respectively, in the new basis. Using $v_0 = Q^{-1} v$ and $w_0 = Q^{-1} w$, we obtain $v^* A w = v^* (Q^{-1})^* B Q^{-1} w$. This should be satisfied for any $v$ and $w$. Thus $A = (Q^{-1})^* B Q^{-1}$ and this implies
$$B = Q^* A Q.$$